# How to sustain shift-selection with my custom scroll function

Tags: key-bindings

I have made two custom scroll functions (that scroll up and down a page respectively)

```
(defun jd:scroll-up ()
  (interactive)
  (scroll-down-command)
  (move-to-window-line nil))

(defun jd:scroll-down ()
  (interactive)
  (scroll-up-command)
  (move-to-window-line nil))
```

I have these functions bound to the keys: <kbd>C-j</kbd> and <kbd>C-l</kbd> respectively.

However, when I hold shift and call these functions the lines do not get highlighted.

This is because of the call to `(move-to-window-line nil)` immediately after.


I'm not quite sure how to go about solving this problem in Elisp.

So is there a way to sustain the shift-selection of text when using this function?

Like is there something I can add to the function to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to replace

```
(interactive)
```

with

```
(interactive "^")
```

in their code.